# how do i add fields to a text file before the last field using awk?

Tags: awk

I have the following space delimited text file:

```
ra dec type
197.574288 -0.673779 coadd
201.236362 -1.007902 coadd
191.573312 5.039784 coadd
```

with "ra" "dec" and "type" as the headers for the file.  I want to use an awk command to add a field with constant value "i" before the last field, and a field with constant value "pdr" after the last field so it looks like this:

```
ra dec i type pdr
197.574288 -0.673779 i coadd pdr
201.236362 -1.007902 i coadd pdr
191.573312 5.039784 i coadd pdr
```

So far, I've tried many different commands, such as

```
awk '{printf("i %s pdr2_wide\n",$3,$5)}' psffile.txt > psf50.txt
awk '{printf($1,$2,$3,"i %s pdr2_wide\n",$4,$5)}' psffile.txt > psf50.txt
awk -F '\ ' -v OFS='\ ' '{ $(NF-1) = i; print }' psffile.txt > psf50.txt <br />
```

EDIT: When I enter the command **"awk '{ print $1,$2,"i",$3,"pdr" }' input"** it gives me a weirdly formatted output:

```
ra dec i type pdr
197.574288 -0.673779 i coadd
 pdr
201.236362 -1.007902 i coadd
 pdr
191.573312 5.039784 i coadd
 pdr
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Please show an example of the desired result.

Comment: Welcome to SO and special thanks for adding your efforts in your question(keep it up). Please do add sample of output too in your question more clarity.

Comment: My apologies! I added the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{ print $1,$2,"i",$3,"pdr" }' input
```

output:

```
ra dec i type pdr
197.574288 -0.673779 i coadd pdr
201.236362 -1.007902 i coadd pdr
191.573312 5.039784 i coadd pdr
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response.  This command makes it so that the "pdr" of each line is beneath the "ra" number. I have edited my question so you can see this output file. I'm not sure why it is doing this.

Comment: This must be because of different line-endings. Normally on unix (or linix) lines en with a CR (carriage return), on Windows lines end on CRLF (carriage return + line feed), and MacOS does somethin else...   I was assuming CR as the end-of-line character.

Comment: @Luuk: Unix/Linux/mac OS uses line feed (hex 0a) and Classic Mac OS uses only carriage return (hex 0d).

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{$NF= "i" FS $NF FS "pdr"}1' file
```

As you want to add fields near at the end, you could do this, for any fields numbers, also `1` at the end means print every line.

Comment: Thank you.  This is giving me the same formatting problem as the suggestion above, where the "pdr" field is entered on a new line every line.  I have edited my question to show what this output file looks like.

Comment: Probably you have special characters, like \r or ^M at the end of the lines. Do you have any relationships with dos/windows? give a try to `dos2unix file > new_file` before the script.